# What exactly is in a doxygen tagfile?

Tags: doxygen

According to the [docs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html) you always use a doxygen tagfile pointing at a set of HTML files. So what exactly does the tagfile itself *do*? For a moderately sized project that generates 700 HTML files my tagfile is 500Kb so there's clearly a lot of stuff in there. But what - why don't I just tell doxygen the location of the external documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tag file is like a precompiled header file for C. It contains all symbols in an external project and for each symbol the deep link to the corresponding HTML documentation. It is just an XML file, so you can open it and see what's inside.

You can't just tell doxygen the location of the external documentation, because then it has no information where to deep link to for each symbol. All it could do is point to the root of the documentation tree, but that is not very user friendly.

In theory doxygen could try to extract the links directly from the generated HTML files.  In fact that was possible in the past, but this is very fragile and did break too often so that feature was removed.

Comment: Interesting feature, is there any tool which can convert a javadoc `package-list` file into a tag file? That would be awesome.